# Is there a setting to prevent Google Scholar from only showing the best matching result?

Tags: productivity, time-management, google-scholar

Often, when searching Google Scholar, I get a single result with a bit of text "Showing the best result for this search. *See all results*" and I have to click on that hyperlink at the end to actually see a full set of results. **Is there any setting to automatically have that clicked so that Google Scholar displays a full set of results automatically, instead of only showing one?**

Example:

---

[image: Google Scholar results page illustrating what's described above]

---

I've already gone in to Google Scholar Settings and Results Per Page is set to 10; making it 20 doesn't help.  Neither of those values are "1," which is what actually gets displayed.

Comment: I know it is not relevant to your question, but would you mind sharing what your search terms in Google Scholar were to produce the result in the image? [I'd be curious to see if I can replicate your results.]

Comment: @MadJack Click on the screenshot - does that do it for you?  (Middle-click to open in new tab.)

Comment: Do a search with the conjunctions **and** and/or **in** omitted.

Comment: it looks like you've searched for something that (intentionally or not) is an exact match for an article title. In this case, I think that the result you got is exactly what I would hope for.

Comment: Though it shouldn't matter for the purposes of this question, it's not.

Comment: My bad, I thought that was a screenshot :-) Thanks.

Comment: @MadJack It is a screenshot, and also a hyperlink.  "It's not [exactly the result I was looking for]" was a reply to Phil.

Comment: I gathered that, but I suppose I was interested because I've never seen this kind of result, even when I've wanted it!

Answer (score 2):

I think you got a single result because your search matched the title of the article exactly.

I replicated your search and removed "and" and "in" -- and my results were significantly different than yours.

Moral of the story: try removing articles, prepositions, and other function words that are frequently part of titles but offer little in the way of content.

[image]

Comment: It is interesting to note that, in OP's example, clicking on "see all results" yields "about 478,000" results, and in your example, "about 477,000" results were generated.

Comment: This answer should probably credit [adipro](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/74707/is-there-a-setting-to-prevent-google-scholar-from-only-showing-the-best-matching/74799#comment181541_74707) as it matches the comment above.

Comment: @WBT I didn't notice the comment, but you're right, adipro got it first

Comment: Sometimes it's worth pasting an exact title (especially in quotes) if all the words used are common in the field.  Also pasting a title and then going through deleting the little words seems a bit tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the contents of the address bars:

`scholar.google.com/scholar?lookup=0&q=Differentiation+and+integration+in+complex+organizations&hl=en&as_sdt=0,39`

for the full results and:

`scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Differentiation+and+integration+in+complex+organizations&hl=en&as_sdt=0,39`

where the difference is `lookup=0&` after `google.com/scholar?` and before `q=...` (though the location of the `lookup=0` bit doesn't matter so we can append `&lookup=0`

Here's a greasemonkey script (firefox) that does the job (updated to fix a couple of bugs, see below).

```
// ==UserScript==
//  @name        Full  Scholar
// @namespace   Example
// @description Add &lookup=0 to google scholar links
// @include     http://scholar.google.com/scholar*
// @include     https://scholar.google.com/scholar*
// @include     https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar*
// @include     http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
var url = window.location.href;
if (! /lookup=0$/.test (url)) {
    window.location.href = url + '&lookup=0';
}
```

So you need to install greasemonkey (on Chrome, apparently tampermonkey is the equivalent) and paste this is as a new script.

Bug fixes 2016-08-09:

- redirects to local google domains were broken (I've added .co.uk, substitute as required)
- some pages were broken, giving a 404 error.  These didn't have `/scholar` in them, so I've added that to the URL match.

(Note, this is my first greasemonkey script and I don't really do js, so criticism appreciated)

Comment: Appending "&lookup=0" to the end of the URL would have the same effect, if there's a script for that.

Comment: @WBT good point, might make it easier